# how to print or define variable in squarespace

Tags: squarespace

i'm going to create a number based on content collection post, i need to know how many post in one collection:

so i need to create something like this
(1/5) / (2/5) / (3/5) / (4/5) / (5/5)

since we can use {.repeated section items}, and also can use {.equal displayIndex 0} to detect the first post

how to print total post in items?

how to print displayIndex? i cannot print the value like this too { displayIndex }

how to define a variable?

{.repeated section items}

{ define variable x = 0} --> im going to do this

{ define x + 1 } --> and this

{.end}

thx...

Answer (score 1):

You can define a variable by using the [`{.var @variable __data__}` directive](https://developers.squarespace.com/jsont-directives/#VarDirective). This workflow is tied directly to the JSON data that Squarespace backend is serving (`?format=json-pretty`) and I haven't seen a working implementation of passing a custom variable (something you define directly in the code).

Something like `{.var @number 1}` is not implemented by Squarespace JSON-T.

Squarespace has `{@index}` variable that carries the [Collection position of the item](https://developers.squarespace.com/jsont-directives/#RepeatedSection) starting with natural 1. In the blog, the most recent posts will have an index of `1`.

And finally, each Squarespace `collection` has a JSON key `.itemCount` that holds the number of items in that Collection.

## Your Solution

```
{.var @numberOfItems collection.itemCount}
```

*This `{.var}` definition must be in global scope to make the `itemCount` value available inside items loop (below).*

```
{.repeated section items}
    {.var @currentItem @index}
    {.if title}
        <h1>{title}<span class="postItemCount">{@currentItem}/{@numberOfItems}</span></h1>
        {##}..additional post data goes here..{##}
    {.end}
{.end}
```

### Notes

- `{.if title}` is an optional check for correctness of post data. If there is no title then nothing gets displayed.
- I've put the count next to the title but you can format it any way you want.
- You an also add additional check for specific `@index` and style that span accordingly. Refer to Squarespace template code for examples on how to add parametric classes in JSON-T.